# Using a callback inside of AWS Lambda handler

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, promise

I've been struggling with trying to output the success/error of my promise chain.

I am chaining promises together like this

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    Q.allSettled(init()).then(function (result) {

    requestValid(event.queryStringParameters)
        .then(isDuplicate)
        .then(process)
        .then(insertData)
        .then(displayResponse)
        .catch(function (error) {
            // Handle any error from all above steps
            console.error(
                'Error: ' + error
            );
            callback({
                statusCode: 500,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: error
                }, null)
            });
        })
        .done(function () {
            console.log(
                'Script Finished'
            );
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: 'Done'
                })
            });
        });
    });
};
```

I am calling `Q.defer.reject(error_message);` on fail and `Q.defer.resolve(success_message)` on  success inside of the promises. If any of these promises fail, the error is being caught in `.catch(function (error) {`.

That's all fine but how do I return this data to the handler's callback?

Example of what I want to do, but don't how/where to put it because of the promises...

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    let response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('some success or error')
    };

// Return all of this back to the caller (aws lambda)
    callback(null, response);
};
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: seems you are comminucating with AWS API Gateway.. Anyway, try to replace all functions by arrow functions , and let me know if it will work!

Comment: Could you please clearify your question? 
First of all why you call callback with 'null' value even if error occured? 
Actually what is the current behavior of the function, does it finish only via timeout or what?

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov i want to know properly use of the callback function when using promises. I have updated this. I was under the impression that it didn't matter which parameter was used, as I only want to return this callback to lambda. I wasn't aware that they behaved different, despite one being for error and the other for success.

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems like your success response should work but you're doing the error the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

[Chain your promises all the way you usually do it](https://dev.to/azizhk110/javascript-promise-chaining--error-handling). Return the result on the last step of the chain. `catch` errors at the end, and return the error if any:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

   RequestIsValid(event)
    .then(isDuplicate)
    .then(process)
    .then(insertData)
    .then(getResponse)
    .then(function(result) {
        //result would be the returning value of getResponse.
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'Done',
                response: result
            })
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // this will show on CloudWatch
        console.error(
            'Error: ' + error
        );
        // this will be the response for the client
        callback({
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: error
            }, null)
        });
    })

// end of the function
}
```

That's assuming that `isDuplicate`, `process`, `insertData` and `getResposne` return a promise and the result of each can be chained to the next one.